# Modify lists defined by other lists

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game but cant figure out how to modify the list without affecting another one. 
My code is

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
list2 = list1
for i in range(len(list2)):
    list2.remove(i)
print (list1)
print (list2)
```

and the result is

```
[]
[]
```

How can i make it so the two are not connected (I need to combine lists but there removed once the program restarts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `list2` a new object:

```
list2 = list(list1)
```

So the output would be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[]
```

Comment: This will not work for compound lists. Try changing the inner list of [[1,2,3],4,5].

Comment: @ManishJain are you sure about what you speaking? see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Let me clarify my stand with an example. Suppose list1 is [[1,2,3],4,5]. Then you do list2=list(list1). Now list2.append('anything') would not modify list1 but list2[0].append('anything') would modify list1 as well. Try this.

Comment: @ManishJain reproduced the issue BTW I reckon The OP would likely hit that issue, *BTW was it worth downvoting??*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42510/discussion-between-manish-jain-and-k-dawg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy module

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
import copy
list2 = copy.copy(list1)
```

Any change in the list1 will not effect list2 and vice versa. If your list is a compound list i.e. contains list as elements, you need to use deepcopy as follows:

```
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
```

For more use cases see http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the first list:

`list2 = list(list1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is good:

```
list2 = list(list1)
```

Or here's the way I usually do it:

```
list2 = list1[:]
```

The first is using the list constructor.  The second is using a slice.  I haven't bothered to check which is faster.